# Textbook for rigorous probability for self study?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm reading GTM 261 (*Probability and Stochastics*), I really love it and it's quite easy to understand, however it doesn't provide a solution manual for its exercises. Is there any other better, or the same good one which does provide solutions?

Comment: I enjoyed [Probability](https://amzn.to/3O6dvLv) by Jim Pitman - it has solutions for every odd numbered problem at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in an introduction to probability, you can read "Probability: Theory and Examples" by R. Durrett. Even though there are no solutions in the book, there is a book or smth on the internet with solutions to many problems. Another resource is "Introduction to Probability Theory" by W. Feller with answers to most of the problems at the end of the book.

If you are interested in stochastic analysis, an excellent recourse is "Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus" by I. Karatzas and S. Shreve. There are solutions to most of the essential problems at the end of every chapter.